# Template template parameters in c++. Using instance

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, instance

I instance a template and want to use that instance for other template

```
template <typename I> class A
{
  I name;
  public:
  A(I n){
    name = n;
  }

  void show() const
  {
   cout << name << "\t";
  }
};

template <template<typename I> class V> class B {
V origen;
public:
B (V o){
   origen = o;
}   

};

auto main() -> int
{
      cout << "[code.cpp]" << endl;

    A<int> a1(1);
    a1.show();
    B<A> b1(a1);
    return 0;
}
```

What I see about this topic is that´s not usually use, but when use, not used in this form, and I don't understand why.
I tried using const. Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`V origen;` and `void B (V o)` are invalid as `V` is not a type.

Maybe you want

```
template <typename T> class B;

template <template<typename> class V, typename T>
class B<V<T>>
{
    V<T> origen;
public:
    B (V<T> o) : origen(o) {}
};
```

and then

```
A<int> a1(1);
B<A<int>> b1(a1);
```

Or maybe

```
template <template<typename> class V>
class B
{
    V<int> origen;
public:
    B (V<int> o) : origen(o) {}   
};
```

and then

```
A<int> a1(1);
B<A> b1(a1);
```

Comment: only one mistake, mine, with the "void" type in the constructor, constructors are not typed

Comment: Error fixed in both side.